# How to create dynamically changing table in mysql database based on current timestamp

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hi I have some employee records in MySQL db, and I use PHP to display those records as report. Now I am stuck with some issue, my employee record have future details like whether they are available in a position or not at some point of time. It records details upto 16 weeks ahead of current week. Now I implemented like for each week separate column in the DB, that I created for testing.

Screenshot of my DB - Dates are highlighted using yellow
[image]

But the problem now is I have to manually delete the first date column and add new column at end every week and also I have to update the HTML Form which I used for getting input data.

```
<form>
                    <table>
                          <tr>
                            <td>Name:</td>
                            <td colspan="5"><input type="text" size="40"/></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td>Domain: </td>
                            <td><input type="text" size="10"/></td>
                            <td>Project: </td>
                            <td><input type="text" size="20"/></td>
                            <td>Area Of Testing:</td>
                            <td><input type="text" size="20"/></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td>EmployeeID:</td>
                            <td colspan="2"><input type="text" size="6"/></td>
                            <td>TKID: </td>
                            <td colspan="2"><input type="text" size="7"/></td>
                          </tr>

                          <tr>
                            <td colspan="6">Billability:</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td>06/22</td>
                            <td><input type="text" size="4"/></td>
                            <td>06/29</td>
                            <td><input type="text" size="4"/></td>
                            <td>07/06</td>
                            <td><input type="text" size="4"/></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td>06/22</td>
                            <td><input type="text" size="4"/></td>
                            <td>06/22</td>
                            <td><input type="text" size="4"/></td>
                            <td>06/22</td>
                            <td><input type="text" size="4"/></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td>06/22</td>
                            <td><input type="text" size="4"/></td>
                            <td>06/22</td>
                            <td><input type="text" size="4"/></td>
                            <td>06/22</td>
                            <td><input type="text" size="4"/></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td>06/22</td>
                            <td><input type="text" size="4"/></td>
                            <td>06/22</td>
                            <td><input type="text" size="4"/></td>
                            <td>06/22</td>
                            <td><input type="text" size="4"/></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td>06/22</td>
                            <td><input type="text" size="4"/></td>
                            <td>06/22</td>
                            <td><input type="text" size="4"/></td>
                            <td>06/22</td>
                            <<td><input type="text" size="4"/></td>
                          </tr>
```

Is their any way to overcome such situation dynamically ? Or Is their any kind of script which will automatically trigger these update on every week ?

Comment: I don't know if you can delete and add columns dynamically, but maybe you could have 16 fields (week1, week2, week3 or however you want to call them) and a `lastWeek` field, in which you store what week field is the last one you modified. When you add a new week, you replace the week(lastWeek+1), and increment `lastWeek` field. So that way you will always have the last 16 weeks in your table. The only problem with this is you can't store the exact date.

Comment: I heard about CREATE EVENT in MySql. Will it be usefull in this case ?

Answer (score 4):

Ideally you would have another table with:

EmpID
Date
Record

Then you would have:

1, "2015-05-01", 3

2, "2015-05-02", 1

etc

Then just add the dates whenever they are inserted, or run a cronjob everyweek to add 7 days to every employee.

Comment: Agreed, Please have a look at database normalization. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: On principle, I would suggest to make __empID__ + __Date__ a single index, either __PRIMARY__ or __UNIQUE__ to avoid potential duplicates.

Comment: @Alexandre in that case we need to manually update the table if we are not using any jobs right ?

Comment: Depending on your logic you might just use MySQL commands such as REPLACE INTO where it would just replace the value if the key already exists, if it doesn't, it inserts.